# How to change UINavigationBar background image when iPad goes from portrait mode to landscape mode?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am making an app in which i an using a logo in UINavigationBar background. When iPad goes from portrait mode to landscape mode then that logo get stretch and looks ugly. I made two different background images both for portrait and landscape mode and then just change it using following code:

```
 -(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
     if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
          NSLog(@"orientation is UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait");

          UINavigationBar *navBar = [[self navigationController] navigationBar];
          [navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"portrait_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

     }else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
          NSLog(@"orientation is UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft");
          UINavigationBar *navBar = [[self navigationController] navigationBar];
          [navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"landscape_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
     }else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
          NSLog(@"orientation is UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight");
          UINavigationBar *navBar = [[self navigationController] navigationBar];
          [navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"landscape_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

     }else{
          NSLog(@"orientation is UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait 2");
          UINavigationBar *navBar = [[self navigationController] navigationBar];
          [navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"portrait_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

}

But thats not working. It is not changing anything. Any idea how can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must use:

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self    selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];

       }

     - (void) orientationChanged:(id)object {  
        UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[object object] orientation];

        if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        {
           NSLog(@"orientation is UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait");

           // Assuming "self" is a view controller pushed on to a UINavigationController stack
          [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"portrait_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        }
        else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        {
           NSLog(@"orientation is UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft");

           [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"landscape_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        }
        else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        { 
           NSLog(@"orientation is UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight");

           [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"landscape_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        }
        else
        {
           NSLog(@"orientation is UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait 2");

           [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"portrait_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
      }
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
    {
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: did not help. And there is one warning Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'UIDeviceOrientation' (aka 'enum UIDeviceOrientation') to different enumeration type 'UIInterfaceOrientation' (aka 'enum UIInterfaceOrientation')

Comment: its showing logs but not changing UINavigationBar background image